# Add JavaScript into a specific content type

Tags: 7, javascript

I would like to know what is the best way to add a JavaScript file into a specific page basing on the content type. For example, I want to add this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

So far, what I have done is using this way to add into my specific content type. For the  map_page content type, I adde the below two line of code in page--map_page.tpl.php.

```
drupal_add_js("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", 'external');
$scripts = drupal_get_js();
```

Is there any other better way? if possible can give some example, currently not really understand well...

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment on the proper Drupal 7 equivalent, but in Drupal 6 sites I do this in a [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6).

I will have some logic to make the decision (either based on `arg()` or `page_manager_get_current_page()` from panels), and then prepend `$vars["scripts"]` with the external script.  I prepend so that I don't run into dependency trouble with any local scripts.

I will also sometimes set up a new region called `$global_scripts` for thinks like Google API and SWFObject that I want to load from a CDN, and this gets printed out before `$scripts` in the page template.

To be honest, though I normally have all JS on all pages so that the files get cached.

Answer (score 6):

Since Drupal won't let you redefine `template_preprocess_node` (because it's already defined in node.module), I added a preprocessor function in my custom module:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['type'] == 'my-node-type') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/myjs.js');
  }
}
```

I used `preprocess_node` rather than `preprocess_page` because it's easier to get to the node type. If you actually reference a javascript file, then it will be automatically cached ([see Parameters section](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)).

Answer (score 2):

you could also use hook_node_view check for the content type and then add the js in the way you are doing already.

OR

If you have a field which outputs the information which will use the JS use a preprocessor there to add the js, so the js include is dependent on the field displaying the map rather than the content type.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to just place the add_js:

```
  drupal_add_js('drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/myjs.js');
```

in the page/node template.php.